# How to return an observable that combines results of another observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

The goal is to retrieve a document from firestore, and for each document, complete it with an array of documents coming another collection.

Firestore isn't supporting the "inclusion" of subcollection.

In my cases, I've a `Test`, which has a whole array of "TestResults". The name of the test results is the firebase ID.

So far, I've the following:

```
const result = this.firestore
         .doc<Test>(`tests/${testId}`)
         .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
         .pipe(
            switchMap((test) =>
               this.firestore
                  .collection<TestResult>(`tests/${test.id}/results`)
                  .valueChanges({ idField: 'name' })
                  .pipe
                  //How to assign my testResults[] to my current test
                  //And how to return a test?
                  ()
            )
         );
```

I guess I do a `tap(results=>test.results =results)`, but then `result` would not be a `Observable<Test>`.

How would you achieve this? The same logic will be used to get all tests.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: use `map` instead of `tap` and let map returns the `test` object after changing its `results`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `tap` and let it returns the `test` object after changing its `results`.

Try the following:

```js
const result = this.firestore
  .doc<Test>(`tests/${testId}`)
  .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
  .pipe(
    switchMap(test =>
      this.firestore
        .collection<TestResult>(`tests/${test.id}/results`)
        .valueChanges({ idField: 'name' })
        .pipe(
          map(results => {
            test.results = results;
            return test;
          })
        )
    )
  );
```